# How to hiding search box from logged-out users

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm working in a WooCommerce WordPress page. 
Is there a way to hide the search box when someone isn’t logged in, or user is not active yet?

Comment: What do you mean "not active yet"?

Comment: if the vendor is not approve from admin (Pending Vendors )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find from where your search box is rendered. It could be the theme header file or somewhere else. I can't say for sure since I have no information on what theme you use etc.

However, find the search box container element, and use as below

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Your usual search function goes here
    } else {
        // Show some message for user to log in, etc..
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm using Martfury theme

Comment: does this helps you? Im sorry Im not familiar with that theme and since it's not a general wordpress theme, I cannot help you just with theme name

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: I'm not finding where the search is rendered.

Comment: load your site, use inspector tool(F12) and inspect your search box. look for search box class value. copy it. open your ide (I assume you use either sublime text or notepad++), search in your project folder for that class. or if you have a live site, share the url